# Show a random variable is independent of a sigma algebra

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, conditional-expectation, independence

I am stuck with the following doubt (for which I cannot find a proof, or a counter example). Let us have $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq0}$ as a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Let us have a process $X = (X_t)_{t \geq0}$

Is it true that:
$$\text{if} \ \ \ \ \ \mathbb{E}\left[f( X_t) | \mathcal{F}_s \right] = a$$
$$\text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \mathbb{E}\left[f( X_t) \right] = a$$
$$\text{then} \ \ \ \ \ \ X_t \ \ \text{ is independent of} \ \ \ \ \mathcal{F}_s ?$$
where $f()$ is a deterministic, continuous function and $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For all $f$ or a particular $f$?

Comment: Ok, in my case $f()$ is deterministic, positive and continous. But I am also interested what happens in general. And also if this way is wrong, how to show indepence of X wrt Fs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is true for every deterministic continuous function $f$, then you do have $X_t$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$.  The reason is that you can approximate the indicator function of a Borel set $B$ by continuous functions to show that it holds for indicator functions, then using the definition of conditional expectation we have for every $A \in \mathcal F_s$ that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[1_A 1_{X_t \in B}] = \mathbb{E}[1_A \mathbb{E}[1_{X_t \in B}|\mathcal F_s]] = \mathbb{E}[1_A]\mathbb{E}[1_{X_t \in B}] = P(A)P(X_t \in B).
\end{align*}
Since $\sigma(X)$ is generated by sets of the form $\{X_t \in B\}$, this shows $X_t$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$.

If you just know it is true for a particular deterministic continuous function $f$, you can't say anything.  For example, the constant function $f(x)=a$ for all $x$ satisfies those conditions for any $X_t$ and $\mathcal F_s$.